# how to disable security for specific url to retrieve access token in speing security 4 xml configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, security

I developing some rest application and have problems with configuration of spring security.

Help me with my xml configuration for spring security 4 in my rest aplication.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<import resource="classpath*:securityServicesContext.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath*:businessServicesContext.xml"/>

<sec:http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="stateless" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="webSecurityExpressionHandler"/>
    <sec:custom-filter ref="customTokenAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/rest/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
    <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
</sec:http>

<sec:authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="unauthorizedEntryPoint" class="com.itechart.security.web.security.UnauthorizedEntryPoint"/>

<bean id="customTokenAuthenticationFilter"
      class="com.itechart.security.web.security.CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="defaultFilterProcessesUrl" value="/rest/**"/>
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean class="com.itechart.security.web.security.TokenSimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

When I send username&password to /rest/login I catch in the CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter and authentication failed. How I can configure my xml to /rest/login request was without filtering and other /rest/** with filtering?

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

```
<display-name>Security Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcherServlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/SecuritySampleDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/app/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

UPDATE 1:

```
public class CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter.class);
private String excludedUrl;

public CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter(String excludedUrl, String defaultFilterProcessesUrl, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler) {
    super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
    this.excludedUrl = excludedUrl;
    super.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(defaultFilterProcessesUrl));
    setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler);
}

public final String HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN = "X-CustomToken";


/**
 * Attempt to authenticate request - basically just pass over to another method to authenticate request headers
 */
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
    String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_SECURITY_TOKEN);
    logger.info("token found:" + token);
    AbstractAuthenticationToken userAuthenticationToken = authUserByToken(token);
    if (userAuthenticationToken == null)
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException(MessageFormat.format("Error | {0}", "Bad Token"));


    return userAuthenticationToken;
}


/**
 * authenticate the user based on token
 *
 * @return
 */
private AbstractAuthenticationToken authUserByToken(String token) {
    if (token == null) {
        return null;
    }
    AbstractAuthenticationToken authToken = null;//todo
    try {
        return authToken;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Authenticate user by token error: ", e);
    }
    return authToken;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (((HttpServletRequest) req).getRequestURI().endsWith(excludedUrl)) {
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    } else {
        super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    }
}
}
```

Here is log, when I send request:

```
21:14:00.805 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/rest/test'; against '/rest/**'
21:14:00.808 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/test at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
21:14:00.818 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/test at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
21:14:00.826 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/test at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
21:14:00.826 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.writers.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1fd019da
21:14:00.827 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/test at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CustomTokenAuthenticationFilter'
21:14:00.827 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/test at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
21:14:00.836 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/test at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
21:14:00.838 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
21:14:00.839 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/test at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
21:14:00.839 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/test at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
21:14:00.840 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/rest/test'; against '/rest/login'
21:14:00.842 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/rest/test'; against '/rest/test'
21:14:00.842 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /rest/test; Attributes: [permitAll]
21:14:00.843 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
21:14:00.862 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@66e0e4e6, returned: 1
21:14:00.862 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
21:14:00.862 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
21:14:00.863 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /rest/test reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
21:14:00.925 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rest/test] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
21:14:00.933 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
21:14:00.933 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a check for `url` in your `customTokenAuthenticationFilter` and bypass filtering rules in case if target is `/rest/login`.
consider this example:

```
    @Override
    protected final void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException,
                    IOException {
        if (!request.getRequestURL().toString().endsWith("rest/login")) { 
            ... apply filtering logic...
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what was I looking for.

Comment: And which filter you are extended to override doFilterInternal?

Comment: @slesh spring provides filter implementations like OncePerRequestFilter where you have to override #doFilterInternal

Comment: Can you help more? Now, I always get 404 error, though in log I see:21:13:52.456 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/rest/test]}" onto public void com.itechart.security.web.controller.LoginController.test(). And when I execute the command curl -i -X GET http://localhost:8080/rest/test I get 404. Why it happens?

Comment: @slesh could you share customTokenAuthenticationFilter impl?

Comment: Omg!!! I found solution. Problem was in web.xml(patter url for dispatcher servlet). Here is solution ,that help me - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17580667/2265497